# Devexpress-wpf print all tabs?

Tags: wpf, printing, devexpress

I have 4 tabs, and every tabs have multiple grids.

How can I print these tabs and grids into one file and print it ?

Comment: Show some effort : what have you tried so far ?

Comment: i tried this code   
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2730

but it's not worked too

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working" ? You have to be very precise and provide as much relevant info as you can so people can help you. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "I have several grids on different tabs of a TabControl. I want to preview and print all these grids at once, that is have a single Print Preview window and start a single print job."
is that enough ?

Comment: @muhammedozbilici The code you said you tried... it is for XtraGrid control, which is a Winforms component. Yet your question mentions WPF. So which one is it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know with using the current DXPrinting suite version it is not possible to combine several documents into one. You can track the DevExpress team progress over the corresponding request at : [Document Creation - Make it possible to combine several DevExpress controls into a single print document](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S33132).

For now, you can try the [possible solution](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Attachment/GetAttachmentFile/ee02fbd0-0eff-11e3-94a0-00219b8b5047) provided by Thorsten Stutzmann in the context of the mentioned request (It works correctly to me with two grids, so I believe you can implement your version of this solution for multiple tabs).

**Update (thanks, @Crono):**
With v2015 vol 1.3 official update this feature is supported by DevExpress out of the box:

> We have introduced the **CompositeLink** class, which provides the
>   capability for combining several Printing Links together into a
>   composite document under the WPF platform. To learn how to use the
>   Composite Link to combine contents of several DevExpress controls, see
>   the following code example online: [How to use the Composite Link](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/T249012).

Comment: As of v2015.1.3, this feature is now supported out of the box.

Comment: @Crono Thank you for the information, I have added this information into the answer.